# Flutter Gradle Build Error: Unknown property 'android' for project ':nedo_mobile_lib

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dependencies, build-error

I'm encountering an issue while building my Flutter project, and I'm getting an error message that reads:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 407

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':nedo_mobile_lib'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':nedo_mobile_lib' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':fluttertoast'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':package_info'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':sqflite'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':file_picker'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':open_file'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':nedo_mobile_lib' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

My project includes a local dependency called "nedo_mobile_lib" that I've created myself. Strangely, I'm able to run the project using Chrome, but I'm encountering this error when trying to run it on an emulator or a real device.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? What could be causing the discrepancy between running in the browser and on an emulator/real device? Any insights or guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!